# Convert NSString in NSArray

Tags: php, objective-c

I'm searching for a Objective-C method like PHP's explode function:

```
$string = "Helle#world#!";
$delimiter = "#";
$array = explode ( $delimiter, $string);
```

Result: $array = {"Hello", "world", "!"}

Thanks,
Andreas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`componentsSeparatedByString:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-componentsSeparatedByString_)

```
NSString *string = @"Hello#world#!";
NSString *delimiter = @"#";
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:delimiter];
```